# ERRO PROCEDURE EXECUTA APENAS UMA VEZ APOS PASSAR POR CONDIÇÃO MYSQL

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados, stored-procedures

Estou com um problema em minha procedure, o cenário é que eu tenho valores nulos e não nulos que são campos de chave primária, estou fazendo um datawarehouse. Como todos esses valores precisam ser calculados, ao executar a procedure, caso algum dos valores que são da chave primária passa na condição para que ela não insira nulo a procedure é executada apenas na primeira linha, depois ela para, mesmo tendo outros dados para serem executados.

```
USE `poli_datawarehouse`;
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `quantMessage`;

DELIMITER $$
USE `poli_datawarehouse`$$
CREATE PROCEDURE `quantMessage`()
BEGIN
DECLARE fimDoCursor INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE customerId INT;
DECLARE channelId INT;
DECLARE userId INT;
DECLARE contactId INT;
DECLARE messageType VARCHAR(255);
DECLARE messageDir VARCHAR(2);
DECLARE createdAt DATE;
DECLARE quantMsgType INT;
DECLARE quantInsertMessage INT;
DECLARE idCustomer INT;
DECLARE quantIdCustomer INT;
DECLARE idUser INT;
DECLARE quantIdUser INT;
DECLARE idChannelCustomer INT;
DECLARE quantIdChannelCustomer INT;
DECLARE idMessage INT;
DECLARE auxiliarIdMessage INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE c CURSOR FOR 
SELECT id, customer_id, channel_id, user_id, contact_id, message_type, message_dir, created_at 
FROM polichat.messages LIMIT 10;
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET fimDoCursor = 1;
OPEN c;
WHILE fimDoCursor = 0
DO
    FETCH c INTO idMessage, customerId, channelId, userId, contactId, messageType, messageDir, 
    createdAt;
    IF fimDoCursor = 0 THEN
        SELECT id_customers INTO idCustomer FROM poli_datawarehouse.customers WHERE 
    id_poli_customers = customerId;

        SELECT id_users INTO idUser FROM poli_datawarehouse.users WHERE id_poli_users = 
    userId;

        SELECT id_channel_customer INTO idChannelCustomer FROM 
    poli_datawarehouse.channel_customers WHERE id_poli_channel_customer = channelId;
    
        IF ISNULL(idCustomer) OR idCustomer = '' THEN
        SELECT COUNT(id_customers) INTO quantIdCustomer FROM poli_datawarehouse.customers 
        WHERE name = 'Não há valor referente';
            IF quantIdCustomer = 0 THEN
                INSERT INTO poli_datawarehouse.customers(name, created_at) VALUES ('Não há 
        valor referente', CURDATE());
            END IF;
                SELECT id_customers INTO idCustomer FROM poli_datawarehouse.customers WHERE 
        name = 'Não há valor referente';
        END IF;
    
        IF ISNULL(idUser) OR idUser = '' THEN
            SELECT COUNT(id_users) INTO quantIdUser FROM poli_datawarehouse.users WHERE name = 
        'Não há valor referente';
            IF quantIdUser = 0 THEN
                INSERT INTO poli_datawarehouse.users (name, created_at) VALUES ('Não há valor 
         referente', CURDATE());
            END IF; 
                SELECT id_users INTO idUser FROM poli_datawarehouse.users WHERE name = 'Não há 
         valor referente';
         END IF;
        
        IF ISNULL(idChannelCustomer) OR idChannelCustomer = '' THEN
            SELECT COUNT(id_channel_customer) INTO quantIdChannelCustomer FROM 
         poli_datawarehouse.channel_customers WHERE name = 'Não há valor referente';
            IF quantIdChannelCustomer = 0 THEN
                INSERT INTO poli_datawarehouse.channel_customers (name, created_at) VALUES 
         ('Não há valor referente', CURDATE());
            END IF;         
                SELECT id_channel_customer INTO idChannelCustomer FROM 
         poli_datawarehouse.channel_customers WHERE name = 'Não há valor referente';
         END IF;
    
        SELECT COUNT(*) INTO quantMsgType FROM polichat.messages WHERE message_type NOT LIKE 
        'sys%' AND message_dir COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT LIKE 'l' 
        AND DATE(created_at) = createdAt AND user_id = idUser AND customer_id = idCustomer AND 
        message_dir LIKE messageDir AND message_type LIKE messageType 
        AND channel_id = idChannelCustomer AND contact_id = contactId;
        
        
        SELECT COUNT(*) INTO quantInsertMessage FROM poli_datawarehouse.quant_message WHERE 
        DATE(created_at) = createdAt AND id_user = idUser AND id_customer = idCustomer 
        AND message_dir LIKE messageDir AND message_type LIKE messageType AND 
        id_channel_customer = idChannelCustomer AND id_contact = contactId;
        IF quantInsertMessage = 0 THEN
            INSERT INTO poli_datawarehouse.quant_message(id_customer, id_user, 
        id_channel_customer, id_contact, message_type, message_dir, created_at, 
        quant_msg_type)
            VALUES(idCustomer, idUser, idChannelCustomer, contactId, messageType, messageDir, 
        createdAt, quantMsgType);
        END IF;
        END IF;
        END WHILE;
        CLOSE c;
        END$$
        DELIMITER ;
```

Todos os campos do meu select formam uma única chave. Eu consegui identificar que o 'fimDoCursor' após receber um valor null de alguma das minhas condições ele seta como 1, e para a procedure, mas não consegui ainda resolver o problema. Tentei pegar o erro para ele continuar a procedure mesmo assim, e não funcionou.

Comment: seu loop é controlado pelo `while` mas que não tem relação com os dados que lidos e que "sabe" quando acaba o cursor, me parece estranho isso... tente criar o loop baseado no fetch, algo assim `LOOP    FETCH ... os comandos aqui ... END LOOP`

Comment: O problema @RicardoPontual quando eu executo ela grava uma vez um dado apenas, pq a minha variável fimDoCursor passa para 1, isso pq uma das minhas variáveis das condições que eu criei retorna null. Caso eu retire "DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET fimDoCursor = 1; " ele grava os dados que deveriam gravar, porém retorna o erro "SQL Error [1329] [02000]: No data - zero rows fetched, selected, or processed". Mesmo se eu utilizar o loop baseado no fetch.

Comment: No caso, eu necessito dos valores null, pq estou fazendo um datawarehouse e isso precisa ser analisado também.

Answer (score 0):

Aparentemente, quando se utiliza INTO em alguma consulta ele retorna 1, com isso estava dando erro inserindo apenas um pois atribuía a minha variável fimDoCursor o valor de um ou se caso eu retirasse
`DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET fimDoCursor = 1;`
ele gravava os dados que deveriam gravar, porém retornava o erro
`SQL Error [1329] [02000]: No data - zero rows fetched, selected, or processed`
Consegui com a sugestão do colega Ricardo Portugal de usar o LOOP e a sugestão encontrada [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54453629), então minha procedure ficou assim:

```
loop_label: LOOP
    FETCH c INTO ...;
    if fimDoCursor = 1 then
        LEAVE loop_label;
    END IF; 
    
    ~minhas instruções~

    SET fimDoCursor = 0; -- reseto o minha variável para ela mudar para 1 somente quando acabar todos os dados que precisam ser inseridos e cair no if especificado acima
    END LOOP loop_label;
```